# How does wetting cotton increase its UV transparency?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, water, thermal-conduction, wetting

Anecdotally, a dry cotton T-shirt prevents sunburn better than a wet one.
This has also been [measured](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11982919/) (Gambichler et al., "Influence of wetness on the ultraviolet protection factor (UPF) of textiles: *in vitro* and *in vivo* measurements", *Photodermatol Photoimmunol Photomed.* 18(1):29-35):

> Saturating the fabrics with water had different effects on the UPF,
> UVA, and UVB transmission values. ... For the cotton
> fabrics and the polyester + TiO2 fabrics, UPF significantly decreased.

What mechanism could explain this?  Naively, adding material *decreases* transparency, even adding something as UV-transparent as water.  The cited study shows that it's not an interaction with the skin, and that it doesn't depend on how salty the water is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cotton fibers are somewhat transparent, and much of the interaction of light
with those fibers is scattering at the air/cotton interface.
A wet cotton fiber has a water/cotton interface instead of
air/cotton, and the indices of refraction for water (1.33) and cotton (~1.5) are
similar, so scattering is lessened (nearly straight-through light
travel).

So, the absorption of light by the cotton depends both on the
attenuation AND the length of the path the light takes in entering,
scattering, and exiting the other side of the fabric layer.
Larger scattering with air/cotton interfaces means longer
mean path lengths, contacting more of the slightly-attenuating
cotton fibers.

There is also an increase in likelihood of light exiting the
cotton in the back-reflected direction.   This means, in
clouds of water droplets in air, that a sunlit cloud will be
bright on its upper surface, and dark  on its lower surface.
I think we've all seen that...